# Git: How to get a principal .git and subdirectories with different origins inside that principal .git?

Tags: git

This is my first question here on Stack Overflow so first thing : "Hi everyone !"

I'm currently student in an IT school in France called 42, and I'm asking myself the obfuscated question you can read above.

Because it's so obfuscated I'll try to be really clear, so here it is :

- We work with "projects"
- Each project correspond to a repo on a school server
- Our work is meant to be pushed in that particular repo in order to be evaluated

For instance, I've worked for the past week on a project called "libft" where we try to implement basic libc functions and other useful stuff. I have to push my work to a repo at the address "XXX@XXX.XXX.fr:algo-1-001/2013/par-1-1/libft/nsierra-".
Well, you got it.

Beside to that, I'd like to have a personal Git repo with all the work I've made so far and all the work I'll work on.
For instance, we'll work on a project called ft_ls where we'll have to implement a function working like the "ls" command-line function. This particular project have the address "XXX@XXX.XXX.fr:unix-1-001/2013/par-1-1/ftls/nsierra-".

And here is my question.
I'd be THRILLED if I could, easily, have on the first hand :

- My personal git repo organized like this :

  ```
  personalrepo/

         libft/

         ft_ls/
             ...
  ```

And on the other hand the school repositories which have to correspond to subdirectories as described, but MUST NOT be considered subdirectories but projects as a whole.

Obviously, my goal here is to manage this, at school, with folders organized like my personal repo.

I don't know if I made it clear...

My ULTIMATE goal would be, when I'm in a subdirectory corresponding to a school project, to be able to do something like a simple `git push` and the changes commited to be sent both on the school server (subdirectory considered root directory) and to my personal repo (subdirectory considered subdirectory).

You can ask me anything. I'm totally aware of my unability to express myself clearly.
THANK YOU !

EDIT :

What I've done so far is :

- In my "superproject" directory (in my case what I call personalrepo), I cloned my project repo using this command line `git submodule add XXX@XXX.XXX.fr:algo-1-001/2013/par-1-1/libft/nsierra- libft/` which would correspond in generic to : `git submodule add myprojectrepo myproject`
- Now when I run ls I get :
  `ls -a
  .           ..          .git        .gitmodules libft`
- I then commited, while in the superproject directory, using the simple git commit thing.

**And here is my problem now.
When I go on my sourceforce page, I only see the .gitmodules file, and not the file libft.
How can I do that ?**
Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve my problem :

I did not use any of git function after all. I created a file inside my superproject directory called .gitmodules and manually wrote :

```
[submodule "libft"]
path = libft
url = XXX@XXX.XXX.XXX:algo-1-001/2013/par-1-1/libft/nsierra-
```

And so on and so forth with every project I had.

Then, I just cloned my projects inside my superproject directory. What I had to do was then the simple `git add libft` and it worked like a charm.
Inside my submodules I just edit all I want and when I push it it goes to its origin, when I'm in the superproject directory, every change I do on the submodules can be added and then commited and then pushed on the superproject origin.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think git submodules are the closest thing to what you're looking for — `git help submodule`. They're not always the nicest thing to work with, though.

Comment: Yes actually I've found some informations about this particular function but the thing is it's kind of hard for me to understand it due to language...

What I understood is that I can do something like :
`git submodule add personal_repo subdirectory_of_submodule` but how do I push it to my school server ? Where can I add the school server adress ?

Comment: And most of all, after that :
  - How do I push it ONLY on the school server ?
  - How do I update my personal repo including the submodule ?